# BASH : How to disallow user input " * " , and also what kind of regular expressions should i check for user input?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

How to disallow user input " * "

```
read -p "inputData : " inputData
#user input *

echo $inputData
#here it outputs the current files in the directory... how do we prevent this?
```

what kind of regular expressions should i check for user input?

here is what i got so far...

```
count=`echo "$1" | grep -q "[\*\.\+\?]" `
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quote your variable to prevent pathname expansion

```
echo "$inputData"
```

#### Example

```
$ read -r -p "Gimme input: " ans; echo "You entered >$ans<"
Gimme input: *
You entered >*<
```

Alternatively, you can turn off globbing by first running `set -f` in your script

If you do either of these, you don't need to check for any nasties in the input ***as long as you're not running it through `eval`***

Comment: sorry can you explain what is eva1? and how do i turn it back on?
is it recommended to turn off before user input and turn it back on after that?
so is it like this?
set -f ; read input ; set -f

Comment: @dupdupdup quote the variable instead. But, for future reference, to turn globbing back on you would do `set +f`

Comment: @dupdupdup regarding `eval`, you're best off never touching it. As the saying goes: *if `eval` is the answer, you're asking the wrong question*

Comment: hi set -f or >< dosent solve my problem! the name folders appear now